# extjs ajax call store not loading

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

I apologize ahead if very similar to other posts but I cannot get this to work after working on it for over a week now. Finally got the webservice to return data, I can see the data returned but the store will not load it. Except in one case: when I create an ArrayStore and set the store to loadRawData i see whole response incorrectly in the grid all displayed down one column; but just happy to see the data. Can someone please take a look at this and see why my store is not loading the data and populating the grid:

```
   Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
         { name: 'connTime', type: 'string' },
         { name: 'userName', type: 'string' },
         { name: 'clientName', type: 'string' },
         { name: 'feedUrl', type: 'string' },
         { name: 'dconnTime', type: 'string' },
         { name: 'errMessage', type: 'string' },
         { name: 'ip', type: 'string' }
  ]
});

var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'User'
 });


 Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'http://dfsdfsfsfs/WCFService/WebService1.asmx/getValue',
    method: 'GET',
    success: function (response, options) {
        var s = response.responseText;
        Ext.MessageBox.alert(s, 'WOO WOO');
        myStore.loadData(s);
    },
    failure: function (response, options) {
        Ext.MessageBox.alert('FAILED MF', 'Unable to GET');
    }
});



  var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: myStore,
    stateful: true,
    stateId: 'stateGrid',
    columns: [
        {
            text: 'Query',
            width: 25,
            sortable: false,
            dataIndex: 'userName'
        },
        {
            text: 'Count',
            width: 5,
            sortable: true,
            renderer: change,
            dataIndex: 'ip'
        },
        {
            text: 'Last Updated',
            width: 76,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'connTime'
        },
        {
            text: 'Disconnect Time',
            width: 10,
            sortable: true,
            renderer: change,
            dataIndex: 'dconnTime'
        },
        {
            text: 'Client',
            width: 10,
            sortable: true,
            renderer: change,
            dataIndex: 'clientName'
        }

    ],
    height: 350,
    width: 800,
    title: 'Active Queries',
    renderTo: 'grid-example',
    viewConfig: {
        stripeRows: true
    }
});
```

.....

I even tried a different way of doing this and with this one i don't even see the ajax response returned:

```
 var newStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
    model: 'User',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'http://dfsdfsfsfs/WCFService/WebService1.asmx/getValue',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'd',
            successProperty: 'success'
        },
        success: function (response, options) {
            var s = response.responseText;
            Ext.MessageBox.alert(s, 'LA LA LA');
            newStore.loadData(s);
        },
        failure: function (response, options) {
            Ext.MessageBox.alert('FAILED AGAIN', 'SUCKS');
        }
    }
});
```

EDIT:

Server Response:

```
{"d":{"connTime":null,"userName":"101591196589145","clientName":null,
   "feedUrl":null,"dconnTime":null,"errMessage":null,"ip":null}}
```

"d" root was manually added by me and is not there in original webresponse. I capture it and add the root:

```
{"connTime":null,"userName":"101591196589145","clientName":null,"feedUrl":null,
"dconnTime":null,"errMessage":null,"ip":null}}
```

EDIT 2:

```
  Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
         { name: 'value', type: 'string' },
         { name: 'tag', type: 'string' }
    ]
});


var newStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    model: 'User',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'http://localhost:52856/WCFService/WebService1.asmx/getRules',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'rules',
            idProperty: 'value'                
        },
        success: function (response, options) {
            var s = response.responseText;
            Ext.MessageBox.alert(s, 'LA LA LA');
            newStore.loadData(s);
        },
        failure: function (response, options) {
            Ext.MessageBox.alert('FAILED AGAIN', 'SUCKS');
        }
    }
 });

  var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: newStore,
    stateful: true,
    columns: [
```

Here is the new json I am trying:

```
{"rules":[{"value":"101591196589145","tag":"16"},
 {"value":"102890809752267","tag":"16"},    
 {"value":"107821192690513","tag":"16"},    {"value":"111517428886211","tag":"16"},
{"value":"117389718398171","tag":"16"},{"value":"12099149051","tag":"16"},
```

OK I found what could be the issue with the ext.ajax.request call. At the time the request is made the store is not even defined and thus the data is not loading. How can I get past this?

Comment: The correct way to do it is to declare the proxy on the store and load the store. What does your server response look like?

Answer (score 2):

Here, I will give you an example, just compare with your code.

```
// defining a model
Ext.define('SampleModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'YOUR_ID', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'YOUR_NAME', type: 'string'}
    ]
});

// defining a store
var storeDefinition = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    model: 'SampleModel',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/your/url/path/data.php',
        reader: {
            // you MUST define root and idProperty
            type: 'json',
            root: 'rootList',
            idProperty: 'YOUR_ID'
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the important parts are `root` and `idProperty`. As you specified, `root` is the root node of the `json` object. `idProperty` is the unique id in the json object.

To catch `success` and `failure` response, you should return `success` or `failure` data inside the json object. It doesn't necessary to specify `success` property in `reader` section. For instance;

```
public function dnr_info()
{
    $dnr    = $this->input->get('dnr', TRUE);
    $subsys = $this->input->get('subsys', TRUE);
    $data['success'] = TRUE;
    $data['data'] = $this->dnr->get_dnr_info($dnr, $subsys);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Above function will return `success` property of the json object.

And, here is the returning json object from the server.

```
{"success":true,"data":{"SUBSYS_ART_NR":"136451","ART_NR":"459993","ACTION_DESC":"BAKKAL AKT\u0130V\u0130TES\u0130 (176)","ACTIONS_NR":"130012676","START_DATE":"19.12.2013","STOP_DATE":"16.01.2014","DISCOUNT_TYPE":"SPECIAL PRICE","LEVEL_TYPE":"QUANTITY","LEVEL_IMPACT":"MULTIPLE","BASIS":"ARTICLE","LEVEL_1":"1 ADET","VALUE_1":"5,92","NWW_VK_PREIS":"6.69","KOLLI_VK_PREIS":"6.69"}}
```

```
// here is the another sample for root which is articleList, idProperty which is ARTICLE_ID 
{"articleList":[{"ARTICLE_ID":"193","ART_NR":"225","ART_DESC":"27*1\/5LT.M.NEK.TAMEK.","SORTEN_TEXT":"ELMA","VAR":"1","GEBI":"1","SUBSYS_ART_NR":"225","NWW_VK_PREIS":"14.49","KOLLI_VK_PREIS":"14.49","DNR_ID":null,"STATUS":"0"},
```

Comment: thanks much for the detailed breakdown. I changed my code into a simple example using yours as a template and still nothing. Using fiddler I see that the webservice is not even being called.

Comment: do you think this has something to do with asynchronous calls it that the webservice returns the data but store not created in time

Comment: I have used fiddler and from what I can see is that the url does not even get called; but it is valid if I paste in the browser

Comment: what method are you using? POST or GET?

Comment: GET, and I realized there is something wrong with the webservice as it is still returning xml although it looks like json. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure how you got yourself in such a state. There are plenty of examples of loading a grid in the SDK download. Proxy has no failure/success method.

Fiddle [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2nl). Working code:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

    Ext.define('User', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [{
            name: 'value',
            type: 'string'
        }, {
            name: 'tag',
            type: 'string'
        }]
    });


    var store = new Ext.data.Store({
        model: 'User',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'data.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'rules'
            }
        }
    });
    store.load();

    var grid = new Ext.grid.Panel({
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        store: store,
        columns: [{
            text: 'Value',
            dataIndex: 'value',
            flex: 1
        }, {
            text: 'Tag',
            dataIndex: 'tag'
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I figured out finally to focus on the actual webservice after using your link and found that is must be the webservice as it still returning the content wrapped with <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"> although it looks like json. I changed the contentType to json but still have not figured out that yet. But at least it eliminates problems with the code for extjs. Thanks for additional advice.

Comment: Can't help you any further then. Good luck.